# Receiving error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' when trying to access localhost

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows, github, localhost

I'm attempting to access localhost of a repository I just pulled from Github, and keep getting the error below. I'm using Windows 8.1. I'm one of two developers accessing this repository.

```
    Mysql2::Error

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;` which would grant your root user privileges to that database. Alternatively you could set the first asterisk to the name of the database, which is probably safer.

Comment: When I attempt to run mysqld through the Command Prompt to enter that, I get an error saying "[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details)."

Comment: That's fine, it's just a warning. Are you still able to run the command?